# Add WC notice in checkout after all other notices

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to add an error notice in the WooCommerce checkout using the following code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'validate_checkout_email_opt', 999);

function validate_checkout_email_opt()
{
    if (!$_POST['terms_emails']) {
        wc_add_notice(__('Bitte stimme zu, dass du den Hinweis zu unseren E-Mail- und SMS-Benachrichtigungen gelesen hast.'), 'error');
    }
}
```

The error message is shown, but unfortunately, it is displayed at the top of the list of all errors. I want to place it at the end (because it is the last field in the checkout form), or ideally, place it at a specific position in the list.

I have scanned the core code of WooCommerce but cannot find a filter or action that I can use for this purpose. I have tried many different filters, without success. It is either not shown at all or shown at the beginning.

Setting the 'priority' to '999' also does not help.

Anyone has a solution for this problem? Thanks!

I am using WC V 3.3.5

Comment: can you please show us how you're adding your custom field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing it like this.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'validate_checkout_email_opt', 10, 2);

function validate_checkout_email_opt( $data, $errors )
{
    if (!$_POST['terms_emails']) {
        $errors->add( 'terms-email', __('Bitte stimme zu, dass du den Hinweis zu unseren E-Mail- und SMS-Benachrichtigungen gelesen hast.') );
    }
}
```

sample result:

[image: reigelgallarde.me]